# Detecting contact internal transactions

Tags: wallets, contract-debugging

Say I have a list of addresses whose transactions I want to monitor.

Detecting regular ethereum transactions is easy. Detecting internal contract transfers looks much more complex.

If my research is right, I'll need to essentially Debug all transactions to any contract in the blockchain via parity/get trace modules and see if its trace mentions an ethereum value transfer to my concerned addresses.
Again, in my understanding, I'll have to do this process for all transactions in every block.
I feel like there has to be a better way. The best I can think of is to trigger this process only if the balance of concerned addresses has changed.

This must be something every ethereum wallet must be doing right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's roughly correct, and yes, if you only care about interactions that involve ether transfers, you can probably get away with only doing this for blocks in which the contract's balance has changed. Note, though, that this will miss blocks where two transfers happened with opposite values (e.g. someone transferred in 1 ether and someone else withdrew 1 ether).

> This must be something every ethereum wallet must be doing right?

No, I don't think so. Why would they?

Comment: Interesting. All wallets would care about is whether the balance has changed, not so much the source of the balance change. For my use case it is important for me to determine the exact source of the fund transfer, not just the fact that funds have been transfered.

Comment: Which transaction caused the balance change? That's a question you cannot answer without trace analysis. I felt wallets would be interested in this information for various reasons.